# how to show error of a particular function - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have logged-in and registration modal in my home page. I am using default login and registration system of Laravel. I have to show error in modal if validation fails. To do this I used below code to force the modal to remain open and show error. But the following code open both loggedin and register modal on error. I want to open only one modal and show error in that modal. For example if user is registering then On error only register modal open and show error but here in this case both modals became open.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
      <script>
          $( document ).ready(function() {
              $('#signin_popup').modal('show');
          });
      </script>
@endif

  @if (count($errors) > 0)
          <script>
              $( document ).ready(function() {
                  $('#register_popup').modal('show');
              });
          </script>
    @endif
```

Comment: Check the ids of both modal.

Comment: it is not the issue of id. when error count becomes greater than 1 it open both the modal. see the code in question.

Comment: with the code you wrote ofcourse both modal will show, they are under the same if statement.

Comment: yes, that is my question. for one modal in a page that code will work fine but if there is two or more than two modal in a page then how will I handle error of each modal

Comment: Because the if statements in both cases are exactly the same. You can add an extra condition to differentiate between registering and signing up. Something like (count($errors) > 0 && $page == 'register')

Comment: the page is same but the modals are different for logged in and registration. Is there anything in Laravel through which i can differentiate this.

Comment: The name of the variable doesn't matter, you can call it anything other than $page.

Comment: what does variable represent ?? The id of the modal or something ?

Comment: Literally whatever you want that makes the difference between the two modals. For example the id of the modal, yeah. Something like $modal = "register" and $modal="signin".

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          if($('#signin_popup').hasClass('in')){
        $('#register_popup').modal('hide');
          $('#signin_popup').modal('show');
          }
      });
  </script>
@endif
@if (count($errors) > 0)
 <script>
          $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($('#register_popup').hasClass('in')){
        $('#signin_popup').modal('hide');
          $('#register_popup').modal('show');

          }

          });
      </script>
   @endif
```

Comment: You could have put the js code in the same if statement under the same document.ready. And what happens when both #register_popup and #signin_popup hasClass('in') ?

Comment: Only one modal has the in class at a time because both modal or independent each other.